# wordpress -> when somebody registers give them post adding capabilities

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress programming. I tried to register one account in Wordpress and it got registered as subscriber so he can only read and comment on post. However I have a requirement where I want that when somebody registers I want to automatically give them post adding capabilities too. Is this possible?

If yes, then how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default role to Author by going to the Administrative page, clicking on Settings, and then on the General page change the default role. http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_SubPanel